# Definition of topologically onto map and Covering Spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In the chapter on Covering Spaces in his book *A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology* Massey uses the term *topologically onto* when defining covering spaces (see below for Massey's definition). What does it mean for a map to be topologically onto?
The only thing I found using google is Definition 2.2. in http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/2004/65-683717.pdf. Is that the standard definition? Does Massey's definition agree with the one you can find [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_map)?

Here is Massey's Definition of a Covering Space (he assumes all spaces involved to be path-connected and locally path-connected).

**Definition.** A *covering space* of a topological space $X$ is a continuous map $p: \tilde{X} \to X$ such that the following condition holds: Each point $x \in X$ has an arcwise-connected open neighbourhood $U$ such that each arc component of $p^{-1}(U)$ is mapped topologically onto $U$ by $p$.

Comment: I think it means "homeomorphism onto image".

Comment: Zhen is right; here "mapped topologically" means "mapped homeomorphically." In other words, for each component $C$ of $p^{-1}(U)$, the restriction $C\to U$ of $p$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Ok, so it is simply the definition found on Wikipedia plus some extra assumptions about path-connectedness. Thank you!